# How can I stream Future Data in real time with Streambuilder in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I am fetching my data from my json API with a Future function. The data is properly displayed in screen but is not in real time. I am using my Future function as a stream with the .asStream() method. Do I have to add a listener to this stream? In that case, how can I do that?

```
 Stream<List<dynamic>>? _allMessagesContainedInTheStream;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
      stream: fetchMessagesFromBack4App(widget.usermail, widget.usermailTo,
              widget.title)
          .asStream(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
....
....
```

this is my future function.

```
    Future<List<dynamic>> fetchMessagesFromBack4App(
        String usermail,
        String usermailTo,
        String dogName,
) async {
    
      final queryBuilder = QueryBuilder(ParseObject('MessagesSender'))
        ..whereEqualTo('sender', usermail)
        ..whereEqualTo('receiver', usermailTo)
        ..whereEqualTo('dogname', dogName)
        ..orderByAscending('date');
      final response = await queryBuilder.query();
      if (response.success && response.results != null) {
       return response.results!.toList() as List<ParseObject>;
      } else {
        return [];
      }
    }
```

Comment: calling `asStream()` will not automagically let you receive real time data: it will just create a stream which emits one event, nothing more - the docs say: "Creates a Stream containing the result of this future.

The stream will produce single data or error event containing the completion result of this future, and then it will close with a done event."

Comment: Ok, I see.. do you have a workking example on how to stream data from Future? I know I have to add the information to streamcontroller and then listen to it but do not know hot to implement it

Comment: you have to poll your server somehow, for example use `Stream.periodic`